# Django Simple History + Save Custom User

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-simple-history

I am using Simple History module in django,  I have used below code in my models for saving history

```
history = HistoricalRecords(
    bases=[CustomHistoricalModel],
    user_model='userprofile.UserProfile',
    user_db_constraint=False,
)
```

==========================

```
class CustomHistoricalModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    field1_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, )

    field2_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, )

    field3_user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        null=True,
        editable=False,
    )

    field4_userprofile = models.ForeignKey(
        'userprofile.UserProfile',
        null=True,
        editable=False,
        related_name='%(class)s_userprofile'
    )

    field5_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        editable=False,
        choices=all_CHOICES,
    )




class newTypes:
    CREATED = 'created1'
    CHANGED = 'updated1'
    DELETED = 'deleted1'


all_CHOICES = (
    (newTypes.CREATED, _('Created')),
    (newTypes.CHANGED, _('Changed')),
    (newTypes.DELETED, _('Deleted')), )
```

===========================

```
in Admin.py

class CustomerAdmin(SimpleHistoryAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'address')


admin.site.register(Customer, CustomerAdmin)
```

The problem I am facing is, while i login through my jango application i am getting request.user as UserProfile and I am able to successfully do the things in application.
but when i login through django Admin module, and add data in models, i am getting error as below 500 error.

ValueError: Cannot assign "<UserProfile: UserProfile object>": "HistoricalCustomerTable.history_user" must be a "User" instance.

Presently my application is using inbuilt user table for authentication , and how to make sure to get UserProfile object when we login through admin module also ? , or suggest some ideas

kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,

**Solution-1:**

I have achieved this in very simply way by overriding getuser of simplehistory and assiging to getuser attribute of historicalrecords which is defined in model class .

**Solution-2:**

I have finded other solution override the save_model method before registering the model in Admin.py and handle the users there, thank you